# Не применяется стиль css к <td> в <div>

Tags: html, css

Допустим я выбираю в css td с помощью следующего селектора:

```
div.weekendcell > td {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

div.simplecell> td {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

И пытаюсь сгруппировать несколько клеток таблицы с помощью div:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <div class="weekendcell"> 
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </div>

        <div class="simplecell"> 
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

В итоге стиль по каким-то причинам не применяется к td,хотелось бы узнать почему

Comment: div не может быть в этом месте. Откройте инспектор и посмотрите как на самом деле выглядит DOM-дерево

Comment: Каким тогда образом можно выбрать несколько <td>,вариант ниже не очень мне подходит потому что у меня другие клетки в этой же строке должны быть другого класса

Comment: @MegaMan В таком случае следует задать более подробный вопрос.  http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @MegaMan: вот! Сейчас вопрос развёрнут и понятен. Думаю, что скоро дадут правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в "Инструментах разработчика" браузера, как выглядит DOM для Вашего html-а. Удивитесь.

---

Неправильно:

```css
div.weekendcell>td {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <div class="weekendcell">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </div>
</table>
```

Правильно:

```css
tr.weekendcell>td {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="weekendcell">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
td:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+8) {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

td:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n+14) {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>

    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Давайте класс самим ячейкам:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td class="weekendcell">1</td>
       <td class="weekendcell">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

td.weekendcell {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

---

Также можно использовать colgroup:

```css
colgroup col.cell-a {background-color: #fcc;}
colgroup col.cell-b {background-color: #cfc;}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" class="cell-a">
    <col class="cell-b">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>A1</th>
    <th>A2</th>
    <th>B1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1. A1 </td>
    <td>1. A2</td>
    <td>1. B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2. A1 </td>
    <td>2. A2</td>
    <td>2. B1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а если ячеек будет много одинакового класса,допустим 10 ячеек одного класса и 2 ячейки другого класса в одной и той же строке?

Comment: @MegaMan Все будет хорошо. Доверьтесь нам. У ячеек может быть сколько угодно классов.

Comment: Я понимаю что всё будет хорошо,я просто думал что есть какой-то более удобный и красивый способ задать стиль сразу относительно большому количеству клеток

Comment: Иногда лучше явно обозначить класс в множестве ячеек, чем потом думать, почему эти ячейки выглядят именно так, а не иначе)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вот так

```css
tr.weekendcell > td {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

tr.simplecell> td {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="weekendcell">             
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="simplecell"> 
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```